# How can I make natural rain drops on screen?

Tags: unity, shaders, shaderlab

I'm trying to make rain effect drop with [metaballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs) and trail on screen.I find a clue in shadertoy but I didn't understand how implemented:

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltffzl

unfortunately it have many math calculations and i can't use it in unity because it produces a lag.obviously I should use textures but how can I have trail effect?!

[image]

my idea is using a texture and trail renderer for droping but how can I have metaballs effect?
[image]

---

## Update

I could Implement Metaballs by [This Article](http://patomkin.com/blog/metaball-tutorial/)

https://github.com/smkplus/RainFX/tree/master

but I haven't Idea about trail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can make this effect by following the steps below:

## Particle

[image: Particle]

## RenderTextuer

you can store result by using RenderTexture.
this is example of multipass in shadertoy:

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltccRl

> iñigo quilez: Shadertoy uses multiple passes, one per "Buffer". As the
>   name indicates, this passes store the results in a buffer. A buffer is
>   just a texture. Unity will let you render to textures too.

I created a camera to Rendering particles to RenderTexture:

[image: ax]

[image: RenderTexture]

## GrabPassing

you can grab pass for applying Distortion

I explained it in this post:

[How can I replicate Quantum Break's distortion particle effect?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153965/how-can-i-replicate-quantum-breaks-distortion-particle-effect/153966#153966)

## Blur

by using alpha in color over Lifetime we have simple blur

[image: alphaovertime]

[image: gradiant]

to get better result it's better to use simple blur , but how we achive blur?

**Convolution matrix**

In image processing, a kernel, convolution matrix, or mask is a small matrix. It is used for blurring, sharpening, embossing, edge detection, and more. This is accomplished by doing a convolution between a kernel and an image.

[for more details, please follow this link](https://medium.com/@skylarsalerno/image-convolution-filters-explained-c878f1056e78)

[image: Kernel]

```
 Shader "Smkgames/Convolution"
    {
        Properties
        {
            _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
            [Enum(kerEdgeDetectionA,1,kerEdgeDetectionB,2,kerEdgeDetectionC,3,kerSharpen,4,kerBoxBlur,5)]
            _Kernel("Kernel", Float) = 1
        }
        SubShader
        {
            // No culling or depth
            Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

            Pass
            {
                CGPROGRAM

                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                };

                v2f vert (appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = v.uv;
                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

                float3x3 GetData(int channel, sampler2D tex, float2 uv, float4 size)
                {
                    float3x3 mat;
                    for (int y=-1; y<2; y++)
                    {  
                        for(int x=-1; x<2; x++)
                        {      
                            mat[x+1][y+1]=tex2D(tex, uv + float2(x*size.x, y*size.y))[channel];
                        }              
                    }
                    return mat;
                }
                float3x3 GetMean(float3x3 matr, float3x3 matg, float3x3 matb)
                {
                    float3x3 mat;
                    for (int y=0; y<3; y++)
                    {  
                        for(int x=0; x<3; x++)
                        {
                            mat[x][y] = (matr[x][y] + matg[x][y] + matb[x][y]) / 3.0;
                        }
                    }
                    return mat;
                }

                float Convolve(float3x3 kernel, float3x3 pixels, float denom, float offset)
                {
                    float res = 0.0;
                    for (int y=0; y<3; y++)
                    {  
                        for(int x=0; x<3; x++)
                        {
                            res += kernel[2-x][2-y]*pixels[x][y];
                        }
                    }

                    return  res;
                }

                float _Kernel;

                fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
                {


                    float3x3 kerEdgeDetectionA = float3x3 (    0.0,  0,  -1.0,
                                                        1.0,  0,  -1.0,
                                                        0.0,  1.0,  0.0);

                   float3x3 kerEdgeDetectionB = float3x3 (0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                                                 1.0, -4.0,  1.0,
                                                 0.0,  1.0, 0.0);

                   float3x3 kerEdgeDetectionC = float3x3 (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                                                    -1.0,  8.0, -1.0,
                                                    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);

                   float3x3 kerSharpen = float3x3 (0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                                                    -1.0, 5.0, -1.0,
                                                    0.0, -1.0, 0.0);



                    float3x3 kerBoxBlur = (1.0/9.0)*float3x3 (    1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                                                        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                                                        1.0,  1.0,  1.0);




                    float3x3 kernelSelection;
                if(_Kernel == 1){
                kernelSelection = kerEdgeDetectionA;
                }else if(_Kernel == 2){
                kernelSelection = kerEdgeDetectionB;    
                }else if(_Kernel == 3){
                kernelSelection = kerEdgeDetectionC;
                }else if(_Kernel == 4){
                kernelSelection = kerSharpen;   
                }else if(_Kernel == 5){
                kernelSelection = kerBoxBlur;
                }

                float3x3 matr = GetData(0, _MainTex, i.uv, _MainTex_TexelSize);
                float3x3 matg = GetData(1, _MainTex, i.uv, _MainTex_TexelSize);
                float3x3 matb = GetData(2, _MainTex, i.uv, _MainTex_TexelSize);
                float3x3 mata = GetMean(matr, matg, matb);


                // kernel
               float4 gl_FragColor = float4(Convolve(kernelSelection,matr,1.0,0.0),
                                            Convolve(kernelSelection,matg,1.0,0.0),
                                            Convolve(kernelSelection,matb,1.0,0.0),
                                            1.0);

                return gl_FragColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

**Boxblur**

> A box blur (also known as a box linear filter) is a spatial domain linear filter in which each pixel in the resulting image has a value equal to the average value of its neighboring pixels in the input image. It is a form of low-pass ("blurring") filter. A 3 by 3 box blur can be written as matrix
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur

[image: 1_oos3y1ztoewgsubpdnbvea]

```
Shader "Smkgames/Simple Box Blur"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha


        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

            float4 box(sampler2D tex, float2 uv, float4 size)
            {
                float4 c = tex2D(tex, uv + float2(-size.x, size.y)) + tex2D(tex, uv + float2(0, size.y)) + tex2D(tex, uv + float2(size.x, size.y)) +
                            tex2D(tex, uv + float2(-size.x, 0)) + tex2D(tex, uv + float2(0, 0)) + tex2D(tex, uv + float2(size.x, 0)) +
                            tex2D(tex, uv + float2(-size.x, -size.y)) + tex2D(tex, uv + float2(0, -size.y)) + tex2D(tex, uv + float2(size.x, -size.y));

                return c / 9;
            }

            float4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float4 col = box(_MainTex, i.uv, _MainTex_TexelSize);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

[image: blurbox]

## Repetition

you can use Rendertexture to store previous frame.so you can grab previous frame then blur. by repeating this you achieve blur.

[image: 0fe28c6167db2132d4bb8677fc1b2050--leandro-erlich-argentina]

## Normal

```
float4 distortion = tex2D(_MainTex,i.uv);
float3 distortionNormal = UnpackNormal(distortion);
```

[image: record_2019_03_03_21_35_45_417]

## Conclusion

Final shader:

```
Shader "Smkgames/BrokenGlass3D"
{
    Properties{
        _MainTex("MainTex",2D) = "white"{}
        _NormalIntensity("NormalIntensity",Float) = 1
        _Alpha("Alpha",Float) = 1
    }
    SubShader
    {
Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha 


        GrabPass
        {
            "_GrabTexture"
        }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 grabPos : TEXCOORD1;
                float3 normal :NORMAL;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 grabPos : TEXCOORD1;
                half3 worldNormal :TEXCOORD2;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;

            };
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _Intensity,_Alpha;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.grabPos = ComputeGrabScreenPos(o.vertex);
                o.worldNormal = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _GrabTexture;
            float _NormalIntensity;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float4 distortion = tex2D(_MainTex,i.uv);
                float3 distortionNormal = UnpackNormal(distortion);
                distortionNormal.xy *= _NormalIntensity;
                normalize(distortionNormal);
                fixed4 col = tex2Dproj(_GrabTexture, i.grabPos+float4(distortionNormal.rgb,0));
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

without using alpha in color over Lifetime:

[image: record_2019_03_03_21_48_36_273]

by using alpha in color over Lifetime:

[image: record_2019_03_03_21_48_19_786]

**Source is available:**

https://github.com/smkplus/RainDrop

## There's more!

also you can make Ripples

[image: record_2019_03_04_22_10_25_457]

**Useful Links**

https://80.lv/articles/breakdown-animated-raindrop-material-in-ue4/

https://seblagarde.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/water-drop-2b-dynamic-rain-and-its-effects/

Answer (score 13):

I think you should think about the effect as "calculate a map of where the water is" + "generate a normal vector from that map and use it to offset a background texture lookup".

Breaking down what your example shadertoy does, it just calculates a "trail" to show where the defogging happens:

[image]

Calculates the normals of the circular raindrops,

[image]

and uses that normal map to offset a texture lookup to fake refraction.

If you want the trails done via post-processing in a shader, you should just create the "trail" shape in the shader using some algebra. For example, in the following function, I've overlaid a "wobbly path" and a taper at the head and tail to get

```
float trailDrop(vec2 uv, vec2 id, float t) { 
    // wobbly path
    float wobble = 0.5 + 0.5 
        * cos(120.0 * uv.y) 
        * sin(50.0 * uv.y);
    float v = 1.0 - 10.0 * abs(uv.x - 0.5 + 0.2 * wobble);
    // head
    v *= clamp(30.0 * uv.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    v *= clamp( uv.y + 7.0 * t - 0.6, 0.0, 1.0);
    // tail
    v *= clamp(1.0 - uv.y - pow(t, 2.0), 0.0, 1.0);
    return clamp(v * 10.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Here's a rough POC in shadertoy -- https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlBfz1 demonstrating creating a set of raindrop trails. It looks grainy at small resolutions due to the derivatives resolution but should look better if you fullscreen it.

Edit: [Added an example with overlaid raindrops](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlSBzh)

[image]

Left as an exercise to the reader:

1) Add the small round drops. for inspiration, look at the `StaticDrops` function in your original shadertoy example.

2) Add in high-quality normal calculations. As the `#define CHEAP_NORMALS` option in your original shadertoy example implies, the builtin dFdx is a low-fidelity approximation and you can get better results by manually calculating the derivatives (at the cost of calculating the function 3 times).

3) Randomizing the spacing between the columns. You can widen the columns and then modify the `uv.x - 0.5 + 0.2 * wobble` bit to add a random offset on the x axis. You'll also probably want to take a page out of the original example once again and layer a couple different sized layers of streams on top of each other to get a less uniform look.

Comment: "Metaballs" don't have to be geometry. [The 2D version of the effect can be as simple as an image formed from a sum of radial falloff functions with a threshold](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/69252/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory Noted. removing metaball comment

Comment: The trail itself can be done via a buffer, by fading ( return oldValue*.95 + newdiskposition ).usually people use Perlin noise to perburbate a straight line.

Comment: something like this https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dy3zR I tried to make noisy trail but I couldn't

Answer (score 1):

There was actually [a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19885/simulating-water-droplets-on-a-window) about this years ago, but it doesn't pertain to Unity at all (unfortunately).  If you look at [slide 57](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/GDC06-Advanced_D3D_Tutorial_Day-Tatarchuk-Rain.pdf) of the linked presentation, they mention a grid-based approach.

There's a [somewhat related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33035/zigzag-flow-of-water-along-a-vertical-glass-window) question on Physics SE that you might find interesting.  The link to [droplet.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20130315155351/https://amath.unc.edu/Faculty/mucha/Reprints/droplet.pdf) in the linked question is broken, but it's still on the Wayback Machine.  It goes into some of the mathematics of water running off a few types of surfaces.  Droplets prefer to travel in paths previously used by earlier raindrops, for instance (see p926).

You could probably just model the heads and tails of each "raindrop" and allowing it to zig and zag a bit.  When two elongated raindrops collide, I suppose you could have them combine into a larger and faster-moving raindrop.  The volume of water stays the same.  It's just being moved and shaped by the forces of gravity, adhesion to the glass, and cohesion.