# How can I replicate Quantum Break's distortion particle effect?

Tags: unity, shaders, graphic-effects

Quantum Break has this fantastic particle effect, it's a distortion effect like broken glass. I want know how I can replicate this effect? You can see it below, and [a full video is available on YouTube](https://youtu.be/8xeqsEAo6nc):

[image: record_2018_02_05_16_34_26_307]

[image: record_2018_02_01_22_27_44_971]

Answer (score 105, accepted):

## Pyramid Particle

Unity default particle's shape is quad.
first you need to change this shape to pyramid by using pyramid object or [turns quads to pyramids with a geometry shader](http://www.shaderslab.com/demo-81---quads-to-pyramids.html).

[image]

[image: awd]

## Refraction

To making broken glass effect([Refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction)) you can use
`GrabPass { "TextureName" }` that will grab screen contents into a texture.

> GrabPass is a special pass type - it grabs the contents of the screen where the object is about to be drawn into a texture. This texture can be used in subsequent passes to do advanced image based effects.
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-GrabPass.html

[image: record_2018_02_03_23_09_06_370]

```
Shader "Smkgames/GlassRefraction"
{
    Properties{
        _Refraction("Refraction",Float) = 0.05
        _Alpha("Alpha",Range(0,1)) = 1
    }
    SubShader
    {
Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"}

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        GrabPass
        {
            "_GrabTexture"
        }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 grabPos : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _Alpha,_Refraction;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.grabPos = ComputeGrabScreenPos(o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _GrabTexture;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2Dproj(_GrabTexture, i.grabPos+_Refraction);
                return float4(col.rgb,_Alpha);

            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

## Using mesh normals

Let’s proceed with a shader that displays [mesh normals](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html) in world space.
I used it because I wanted to look three dimensional broken shape.

[image: normals]

[image: record_2018_02_05_18_06_09_41]

[image: record_2018_02_03_23_19_06_705]

```
    Shader "Smkgames/BrokenGlass3D"
{
    Properties{
        _MainTex("MainTex",2D) = "white"{}
        _Alpha("Alpha",Float) = 1
    }
    SubShader
    {
Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
 Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha 


        GrabPass
        {
            "_GrabTexture"
        }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 grabPos : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 normal :NORMAL;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 grabPos : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                half3 worldNormal :TEXCOORD1;

            };
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _Intensity,_Alpha;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.grabPos = ComputeGrabScreenPos(o.vertex);
                o.worldNormal = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _GrabTexture;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 c = 0;
                c.rgb = i.worldNormal*0.5+0.5;
                float4 distortion = tex2D(_MainTex,i.grabPos)+_Intensity;
                fixed4 col = tex2Dproj(_GrabTexture, i.grabPos+c.r);
                return float4(col.rgb,_Alpha);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

## Heat Distortion

To creating heat distortion you can use [flow map](http://acegikmo.com/shaderforge/wiki/index.php?title=Flowmap)

> A flow-map is a texture that stores 2d directional information in a texture. The color of the pixel determines what direction it is using the uv-coordinates texture as a base. The more color there is the faster the proportional speed. Example green tells it to go up-left, the center is neutral, and red will go down right. It’s a useful technique for liquid materials like water, and a useful alternative to just a panner node.

[image: flow_map]

[image: heatdistortion]

```
    Shader "Smkgames/HeatDistortion"
{
    Properties{
        _DistortionMap("DistortionMap",2D) = "white"{}
        _Intensity("Intensity",Float) = 50
        _Mask("Mask",2D) = "white"{}
        _Alpha("Alpha",Range(0,1)) = 1
    }
    SubShader
    {
Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"}

        GrabPass
        {
            "_GrabTexture"
        }

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 grabPos : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };
            sampler2D _Mask,_DistortionMap;
            float _Alpha,_Refraction;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.grabPos = ComputeGrabScreenPos(o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _GrabTexture;
            float _Intensity;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float mask = tex2D(_Mask,i.grabPos);
                mask = step(mask,0.5);
                //mask = smoothstep(mask,0,0.4);
                float4 distortion = tex2D(_DistortionMap,i.grabPos+_Time.y)+_Intensity;
                fixed4 col = tex2Dproj(_GrabTexture, i.grabPos*distortion);
                return float4(col.rgb,mask*_Alpha);

            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

another example by using normal:

[image: cutout]

[image: normalmap]

[image: smoketile_normal 1]

```
Shader "Smkgames/HeatDistortion2" {
Properties {
        _CutOut ("CutOut (A)", 2D) = "black" {}
        _BumpMap ("Normalmap", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _BumpAmt ("Distortion", Float) = 10
}

Category {

    Tags { "Queue"="Transparent"  "IgnoreProjector"="True"  "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    Cull Off 
    Lighting Off 
    ZWrite Off 
    Fog { Mode Off}

    SubShader {
        GrabPass {                          
            "_GrabTexture"
        }
        Pass {

CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
#pragma multi_compile_particles
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

struct appdata_t {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
};

struct v2f {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 uvbump : TEXCOORD1;
    float2 uvcutout : TEXCOORD2;
};

sampler2D _BumpMap,_CutOut,_GrabTexture;
float _BumpAmt;
float4 _GrabTexture_TexelSize;
float4 _BumpMap_ST,_CutOut_ST;

v2f vert (appdata_t v)
{
    v2f o;
    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
    o.uvgrab.xy = (float2(o.vertex.x, o.vertex.y*-1) + o.vertex.w) * 0.5;
    o.uvgrab.zw = o.vertex.zw;
    o.uvbump = TRANSFORM_TEX( v.texcoord, _BumpMap );
    o.uvcutout = TRANSFORM_TEX( v.texcoord, _CutOut );
    return o;
}



half4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR
{
    half2 bump = UnpackNormal(tex2D( _BumpMap, i.uvbump )).rg;
    float2 offset = bump * _BumpAmt * _GrabTexture_TexelSize.xy;
    i.uvgrab.xy = offset * i.uvgrab.z + i.uvgrab.xy;

    half4 col = tex2Dproj( _GrabTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvgrab));
    fixed4 cut = tex2D(_CutOut, i.uvcutout);
    fixed4 emission = col;
    emission.a = (cut.a);
    return emission;
}
ENDCG
        }
    }

  }
}
```

## RGB Split

If you pay attention to your first gif you can see little RGB split.

[image: u_rgb_seperation_ar]

```
Shader "Hidden/RgbSplit"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _NoiseTex1 ("Noise Texture A", 2D) = "white" {}
        _NoiseTex2 ("Noise Texture B", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex,_NoiseTex1,_NoiseTex2;
            float3 colorSplit(float2 uv, float2 s)
{
    float3 color;
    color.r = tex2D(_MainTex, uv - s).r;
    color.g = tex2D(_MainTex, uv    ).g;
    color.b = tex2D(_MainTex, uv + s).b;
    return color;
}

float2 interlace(float2 uv, float s)
{
    uv.x += s * (4.0 * frac((uv.y) / 2.0) - 1.0);
    return uv;
}

    fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
    {

    float t = _Time.y;

    float s = tex2D(_NoiseTex1, float2(t * 0.2, 0.5)).r;

    i.uv = interlace(i.uv, s * 0.005);
    float r = tex2D(_NoiseTex2, float2(t, 0.0)).x;

    float3 color = colorSplit(i.uv, float2(s * 0.02, 0.0));

    return float4(color, 1.0);

            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

## Useful Links

https://www.fxguide.com/featured/time-for-destruction-the-tech-of-quantum-break/

[Source On Github](https://github.com/smkplus/Quantum-break)

Comment: I'm curious, have you considered setting up a developer blog to share techniques like these? I'd subscribe to a resource like that. :)

Comment: I second the suggestion! I monitor the website every day for your responses, as your approach is always creative, detailed, and yet simple to understand. The examples you provide are also of great help.

Comment: Regarding your RGB split effect: I wear glasses and always experience a naturally-occurring similar effect caused by chromatic aberration, varying with eye-to-screen distance.  In the same way that 3D glasses cause a mismatch between various cues of how far away something is, your effect interferes with a detail that my brain interprets to estimate how far the screen is from my eye.  It's extremely unpleasant, to the point of nauseating.  Please make it optional if you choose to use it!

Comment: @Aoeuid FWIW, it's intensely unpleasant even with for people without corrective vision :)

Comment: @DMGregory yep :D.I  haven't a site so I share my techniques here I need your support to developing blog or site.If you support me I will be helpful
[https://www.patreon.com/SeyedMortezaKamaly](https://www.patreon.com/SeyedMortezaKamaly)

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamaly subscribed. I look forward to seeing what you do with it. For content you intend to monetize this way, I recommend hosting elsewhere - either on Patreon or on your own site. That way you can keep using GDSE for free focused Q&A help, and your own sites for tutorial series, samples, and the like, which don't have to conform to a question-and-answer format.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for all your help and encouragement. You always make me feel special. I love you.I will do my best to making tutorials.I'm working on the site now.

Comment: OP, sad news: Even answering your own question this well won't get you back your bounty. Once a bounty is issued, the points are awarded to someone else or to no-one at all. Fortunately it seems you've earned many more points than if you have not posted this question. Well done.